# .toArray() in Javascript returns undefined even with .then()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, return, undefined

I am using mongo to search for all entries with a value that is like whatever is passed into the searchForAsset method. When I use the .toArray method and I console.log(result) the array of files is printed in array format. However when I return that exact same variable below the console.log and I console.log it in the .then() below, it comes back as "result: undefined". Why doesn't the .then() wait for the result to be returned correctly?

```
async function searchForAsset(nameToQuery){
    const client = await mongoConnect()
    client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection(process.env.ASSET_COLLECTION).find({asset_name: RegExp(nameToQuery)}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result)
        client.close()
        return result
    })
}

searchForAsset("Solution").then(result => {
    console.log("result: "+result)
})
```

**Edit**: I changed the code to this and it still returns undefined:

```
async function searchForAsset(nameToQuery){
    const client = await mongoConnect()
    const result = await client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection(process.env.ASSET_COLLECTION).find({asset_name: RegExp(nameToQuery)}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result)
        client.close()
    })
    return result
}

searchForAsset("Solution").then(result => {
    console.log("result: "+result)
})
```

Comment: Why aren't you using await in an async function? `const result = await client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection(process.env.ASSET_COLLECTION).find({asset_name: RegExp(nameToQuery)}).toArray()` or you need to add `return` before `client.db(...)`

Comment: searchForAsset is not returning anything. If there's no return statement in a function, you will get `undefined`

Comment: @Dharmaraj @Evert if I change the method to `const result = await client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection(process.env.ASSET_COLLECTION).find({asset_name: RegExp(nameToQuery)}).toArray(function(err, result) {})` and then after that do `return result` it still results in an undefined `console.log()` in the `.then()`

Comment: You don't use call back with `await` generally. Try copying code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/cfd17fc9c05eb9041a8c5680bf184036)

Comment: @Dharmaraj then the return looks like this: `result: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...` and so on

Comment: @Dharmaraj in the command prompt window using console.log("result: "+result)

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `await` as the function is `async` like this:

```js
async function searchForAsset(nameToQuery){
    const client = await mongoConnect()
    const result = await client.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME).collection(process.env.ASSET_COLLECTION).find({asset_name: RegExp(nameToQuery)}).toArray()
    return result 
}

searchForAsset("Solution").then(result => {
    console.log("result: "+result)
})
```

About that `[object Object]` being logged. Try stringifying that:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Then to view it in a prettier way, copy the log output and paste it in https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: yes the `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` works but for large outputs its just a wall of text, how can I turn this back into a json that looks nice

Comment: @RileyEaton like view it yourself or in your app? Try using the [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/)